# Manipulation of Large Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

I encountered a puzzling problem (though I don't remember where) to find the prime factorization of the number
$$7^{100}-1$$
I think there may be some kind of trick or technique that one could use to solve this problem that I am unaware of. I already know the fact that any number of the form $c^n-1$ is divisible by $c-1$, so I know that $7^{100}-1$ is divisible by $6$, but now what do I do?

Comment: You could start by recalling the factorisation of $x^n-1$ into cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: Hint (to get started): $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$. More generally, $a^n - b^n = (a-b)(??)$. Also, if $n$ is odd, $a^n+b^n=(a+b)(??)$.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem tells us that 101 is a prime factor as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of the difference of two squares:

$$\begin{align}7^{100}-1&=(7^{50}+1)(7^{50}-1)\\&=(7^{50}+1)(7^{25}+1)(7^{25}-1)\end{align}$$

Then recall $a^5-b^5=(a-b)(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)$ to get

$$\begin{align}7^{25}-1&=(7^5-1)(7^{20}+7^{15}+7^{10}+7^5+1)\\&=(7-1)(7^4+7^3+7^2+7+1)(7^{20}+7^{15}+7^{10}+7^5+1)\end{align}$$

Likewise, $a^5+b^5=(a+b)(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4)$, so we have

$$\begin{align}7^{25}+1&=(7^5+1)(7^{20}-7^{15}+7^{10}-7^5+1)\\&=(7+1)(7^4-7^3+7^2-7+1)(7^{20}-7^{15}+7^{10}-7^5+1)\\7^{50}+1&=(7^{10}+1)(7^{40}-7^{30}+7^{20}-7^{10}+1)\\&=(7^2+1)(7^8-7^6+7^4-7^2+1)(7^{40}-7^{30}+7^{20}-7^{10}+1)\end{align}$$

We see that

$7-1=6=2\times3$

$7^4+7^3+7^2+7+1=2801=\text{prime}$

[$7^{20}+7^{15}+7^{10}+7^5+1=79797014141614001=2551\times31280679788951$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E20%20%2B%207%5E15%20%2B%207%5E10%20%2B%207%5E5%20%2B%201%20prime%3F)

$7+1=8=2^3$

$7^4-7^3+7^2-7+1=2101=11\times191$

[$7^{20}-7^{15}+7^{10}-7^5+1=79787519018560501=\text{prime}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E20%20-%207%5E15%20%2B%207%5E10%20-%207%5E5%20%2B%201%20prime)

$7^2+1=50=2\times5^2$

[$7^8-7^6+7^4-7^2+1=5649505=5\times281\times4021$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E8%20-%207%5E6%20%2B%207%5E4%20-%207%5E2%20%2B%201%20prime%3F)

[$7^{40}-7^{30}+7^{20}-7^{10}+1\\=6366805738369687774841443066497505\\=5\times101\times13001\times25301\times38327966300231909291101$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E40-7%5E30%2B7%5E20-7%5E10%2B1%20prime%3F)

Comment: You switched to WA too early. Pen and pencil still find $7^{10}+1\mid7^{50}+1$ and $7+1\mid 7^5+1\mid 7^{25}+1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Lol, true, I suppose I could do that.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Updated.  Not sure if I can find some nifty trick on the last few.  $7^8-7^6+7^4-7^2+1$ might be doable by hand though.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a number of small factors fairly easily.  As you say, $6$ is a factor.  You can also factor it as the difference of squares.  One of those factors will again factor as the difference of squares.  This brings you to $7^{25}+1$ which has a factor $7+1$.  The difference of fifth powers factors as well.  I doubt you will get the complete factorization, which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%207%5E100-1) says is $2^5\times 3\times 5^4\times 11\times 101\times 191\times 281\times 2551\times 2801\times 4021\times 13001\times 25301\times 31280679788951\times 79787519018560501\times 38327966300231909291101$

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, start from the factorization of $x^{100}-1$ in terms of cyclotomic polynomials:
$$
x^{100}-1=
(x - 1) (x + 1) (x^2 + 1) (x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) (x^8 - x^6 + x^4 - x^2 + 1) (x^{20} - x^{15} + x^{10} - x^5 + 1) (x^{20} + x^{15} + x^{10} + x^5 + 1) (x^{40} - x^{30} + x^{20} - x^{10} + 1)
$$
which comes from
$$
x^n-1=\prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)
$$

This gives
$$
7^{100}-1
=
6 \cdot
8\cdot
50\cdot
2101\cdot
2801\cdot
5649505\cdot
79787519018560501\cdot
79797014141614001\cdot
6366805738369687774841443066497505
$$
It is possible to further factorize this, but it is not easy because $79787519018560501$ is prime and $6366805738369687774841443066497505$ has a prime factor $38327966300231909291101$, though its other factors are quite small.

`factor` from BSD gives

```
6: 2 3
8: 2 2 2
50: 2 5 5
2101: 11 191
2801: 2801
5649505: 5 281 4021
79787519018560501: 79787519018560501
79797014141614001: 2551 31280679788951
6366805738369687774841443066497505: 5 101 13001 25301 38327966300231909291101
```